# Get multiple images in facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rest, facebook-fql, high-availability

I need, in a single call, to retrieve multiple images in a facebook stream.

let's assume that the user token I'm using has the permission to access to all this images, if I need a single image I call:

> graph.facebook.com/PICTURE_ID/picture?type=normal&access_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN_HERE
>   graph.facebook.com/PICTURE_ID_2/picture?type=normal&access_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN_HERE
>   graph.facebook.com/PICTURE_ID_3/picture?type=normal&access_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN_HERE

... {and so on}

but if I need more images in a single call?
I tried something like:

> https://graph.facebook.com/picture?ids=PICTURE_ID_1,PICTURE_ID_2&type=normal&access_token=MY_VALID_TOKEN

but the result was only a single picture... any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it, thanks to this tricky FQL it was quite hard at first, however the correct FQL query is this:

```
fql?q=SELECT pid,src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (12345,23456,34567)&access_token=ACCESSTOKENOFSOMEONEWHOHASACCESSTOTHOSEPHOTOS
```

beware that `object_id` is an integer and so it MUST NOT have " in the `where` clause.

Comment: can you please explain how to get all photos from a single post using FQL. How do we get all ID's ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`fql?q=SELECT src_big, link, caption FROM photo WHERE pid IN ('12','13','56')&access_token=ACCESSTOKENOFSOMEONEWHOHASACCESSTOTHOSEPHOTOS`

Comment: is it possible to test it as an URL in my browser?

Comment: How about trying it here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  You'll learn a tonne by playing around with it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, after studying a bit more FQL, I understood that the table I need to query is the stream, but in the stream is there any possibilities to gather this kind of information?

Comment: Actually it was helpful but it didn't solve my problem (I haven't solved yet!!), I upvote as a sign of appreciation (when you answered me to this question I had not the privilege to upvote), but I can't mark as the best answer until I find a solution for this, hope you understand

Comment: I finally solved! Check my answer if you're interested.. 
The point I was missing is the mother****ing field "object_id" in FQL